# Is it possible to represent a polynomial function/equation for geographic location like country, city in maths?

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

Through functions, **line**, **circle**, **triangle**, etc., shapes can be represented. Is it possible to represent an *irregular shapes like **city**, **country*** or *anything we draw in 2d plan* in math? if possible, how to do that?

Comment: Most likely what you are looking for is vector based graphics.

Comment: @Arjang, how do I approach this problem with vector based graphics. any suggestion? links? martial to refer to plz

Comment: maybe start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system